# How do I add connecting line to 2D arrangement in CGAL?

Tags: 2d, line, point, cgal

I am using 2D arrangements two create connected segments under  `exact_predicates_inexact_construction` kernel.

Suppose I have three Points `a`, `b` and `c`, and two segments `X =(a, b)` and `Y=(b,c)` how do I consistently ensure that vertex corresponding to `b` created only once while I insert them into a 2D arrangement in CGAL? I currently encounter cases where this fails.

Comment: It is ensured. Please post a small test case that reproduces such a case.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to provide some sample code and the error you're getting but if `b` is the same point it will create one vertex.

The most fool proof way to do it is to just pass the segments in as a batch:

```
Point_2 a( 0, 0 );
Point_2 b( 1, 1 );
Point_2 c( 0, 2 );
std::vector<Segment_2> segments({ Segment_2 x( a, b ). Segment_2 y( b, c ) });
Arrangement_2 arr;
insert( arr, segments.begin(), segments.end() );
```